# How to manage GCP permissions to create a subscription and allow deletion of only the subscritpion created by this service account?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a subscription during the application run time, the code should be able to create a subscription and clean it up after it finishes.

I want to do this **with the least possible permissions to the service account** I am using. For now, I have created a custom role and gave two access to the role `pubsub.subscriptions.create , pubsub.subscriptions.delete`.

Although this is allowing the creation and clean up of a subscription, it is allowing not only to delete the current subscription, but also the subscriptions created by other users in the same project.

1. How can I assign permissions, to be able to create subscriptions in Pub/Sub, delete the subscription created by this service account?
   Another way to put it could be, how can I, create a subscription at run time and modify only this subscription's permission to include `pubsub.subscriptions.delete`. (with the same service account).
2. Is there a **way to make a service account admin/editor for the resources**(topics, subscriptions, compute engine, etc.) **created by this account**? something like an IAM role - make admin after resource creation.

Related Documentation Links:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control

Comment: Do you know in advance the name or the pattern of the subscription name?

Comment: Not the name, but the pattern I do have, I use UUID to generate subscription string. 
it will be like, if the generated UUID is 
```uuid_genearted_1```

the name of the subscription will be,
```subscription_gen.uuid_generated_1```

Comment: Can you consider that the service account can delete any subscription with this pattern? Or is there a risk to overlap with another subscription created by other service account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I was not aware of using conditions based on patterns. The pattern is well defined it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: great, I would like to be sure of your use case before testing the condition based on the resource name on my side. But I have to conclude that works!! Cool!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible due to limitations of the Google IAM by design.

In Google IAM **permissions correspond 1:1 with REST methods**. To call a method, the caller needs that permission. In other words, permissions are granted on methods so that call them, and **not on objects** so that modify/rename/delete them, as would be necessary in your case. You want to delete a certain object, right?

To get more granular access, you need to assign a Policy with a Custom Role on a Subscription object explicitly, but you can hardly assign a Pub/Sub Custom Role below the Project level.

A Subscription creator does not become an "Admin" of the created object as it could be in an access management service with permissions assigned on objects. If explicit assigning of a Policy with a Custom Role on a freshly created Subscription was possible, it must be done by an account with a Role that can manage permissions: `pubsub.admin` for example. That means that you would have to grant this Role to your service account in addition to the existing Custom Role with the `pubsub.subscriptions.create` and `*.delete` permissions. As soon as you do this, the least privilege principle becomes meaningless.

[Understanding IAM custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles#basic_concepts)

[Cloud IAM Documentation > Understanding roles > Pub/Sub roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#pub-sub-roles)

[Access Control > Required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#required_permissions)

[Access Control > Roles](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles)

Comment: I think it makes sense to have the permissions being tied to methods. 

If concerned too much on IAM, it would be good to run a separate service for IAM management. Otherwise, we can grant the regular account with the required permissions.

In my case, since the pattern is well defined (in general in most of the applications it will be well defined), I can use the pattern for restricting access.
Thanks for answering the question.

Comment: I really think this by itself already violates the least privilege principle. Basically this means that for anyone to be able to create and use resources, they need the permission to create/edit/update/delete ALL resources in the project. So basically, the ability to create a resource is an ALL or NOTHING permission. You can either CRUD everything, or you can't create at all.

Comment: In the case of pubsub, it basically means service accounts can either subscribe to all topics and edit/delete all subscriptions (i.e. roles/pubsub.editor at the project level) or nothing.